# asbygoogle causes chrome executescript never to return

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a Chrome extension that injects javscript into allframes using

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, { file: "findDoc.js", allFrames:true }, function () {
... }
```

This works well except in the case when the document contains adsbygoogle for example at http://words.loqu8.net/simp_01.html vs http://words.loqu8.net/simp_02.html. In the latter case, it seems that executeScript never returns and the callback is never called.

The adsbygoogle block looks like:

```
<div id="sponsor" style="display:block">
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- CWSJ Front&Article Page (Native-Right) -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-4620242196338906"
     data-ad-slot="6183624152"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

I have tried all runAt options. None of those have any effect. It is as if the adsbygoogle is resisting the executeScript.

The Google Ads are definitely in a frame, so it seems that allFrames:false should at least make it work (it doesn't). Google's iframe looks like

```
<iframe width="336" height="280" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" onload="var i=this.id,s=window.google_iframe_oncopy,H=s&amp;&amp;s.handlers,h=H&amp;&amp;H[i],w=this.contentWindow,d;try{d=w.document}catch(e){}if(h&amp;&amp;d&amp;&amp;(!d.body||!d.body.firstChild)){if(h.call){setTimeout(h,0)}else if(h.match){try{h=s.upd(h,i)}catch(e){}w.location.replace(h)}}" id="aswift_0" name="aswift_0" style="left:0;position:absolute;top:0;"></iframe>
```

**Update.** It turns out I had two scripts injecting, both with allFrames:true. If allframes:false my code works fine. So the real question here is how can I have allFrames:true but skip the adsbygoogle frame. Even if the injected script just contains 'console.log' it causes executeScript never to return.

**Update 2.** Even if the injected script has nothing (commented out everything) executeScript still hangs on the Adwords frame and never returns.

Comment: runAt `document_start` works for me in this scenario, although it only injects into the root document plus the top-level iFrame.  `allFrames` set to false also works (for top level document only obviously)

Comment: steve, thank you for looking into this, you were able to get allFrames:true, runAt:document_start to work? I'll try it.

Comment: do you think there is any way to filter out the adsbygoogle frame?

Comment: yes, it works for me with that combination.  I just tested with my extension on the example page that you linked and it definitely works for the root document.  For the iframe it shows as injected in dev tools console, but I don't think that the callback ran for the iframe inject.  .

Comment: @SteveCampbell - allframes:true and document_start is an acceptable solution. I'm not sure what the implications are but it is acceptable for now. Thank you so much. Write it up and I will choose your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to get it to work for `allFrames` true, but only if I set `runAt` to `document_start`.

In this scenario, the callback definitely executes for the main document, but I could not verify that it runs for the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly, I haven't found something like "exclude_matches" for manifest permissions, with it you can just code 
`exclude_matches:"*://*googleads.g.doubleclick.net"` or something like this.
But, if you don't need these adsgoogle frames, you could

1) switch them off;

2) run your script.

Do two executeScripts: 
First script runs with allframes:false. It just finds all frames with such a host (with jquery, querySelectorAll etc.), and sets them src = ""; (you can save the original source before setting and restore it later, when your main script finish its work). 
Second script is your main script and you may run it in the callback of the first script.